# how does mxm graphics card compatibility work

Tags: laptop, gpu, graphics, pci-express

I have this aio PC that's like a gimpy laptop. It's only GPU expandability is an mxm slot but I've never used them. Do I treat them like pcie without a VGA port in regards to its version standards and are later versions likewise backwards compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much, yea, however like all 'standards' in computing there's more than one:)
see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_PCI_Express_Module), so you'd need to work out what type you needed.

Comment: Yes, I understand wikipedia will help in depth. I was looking to epand the question answer sphere relevant to those who google search and do not speak supergeek.

Comment: fair enough, and it looks like you've already worked out how they work, and from Wiki we can see that backward compatibility is out, so you need the exact type of MXM slot your AIO uses before searching for a supplier.

Comment: So if Im understanding correctly... if i find an exact match for the MXM version. (1,2,3,a,b...) No matter what the card (ati, nvidia, new, old) the bios is unlikely to be hardcoded to a gpu series = and it should work?

Comment: that is the concept yes, it is like pcie, supposed to allow the gpu to be user replaceable.